# should I have put the word "that"?

Tags: meaning, past-tense

Yesterday I sent a message about my work to my boss. The message was this:

> "this is the design  I designed yesterday"

After I sent the message, I started to think maybe I should have added the word "that"

> "this is the design **that** I designed yesterday"

Which one of these are correct, and what does changing it imply?

Answer (score 1):

It's grammatically correct either way and means exactly the same thing with or without it. Leaving it out, as you did, would be the most common form.

[Incidentally: the "design I designed" construction is valid but reads a little awkwardly. I'd go for "this is what I designed yesterday"]

Comment: As Richard says, one doesn't design designs. One prepares/produces/creates (and lots of other possibilities) them.